# Can I use Metamagic (or other spellcasting features) on a spell that I gained from multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing, metamagic

As I understand it, class features only apply to spells you gained through that class. For example, I can't use the Distant Spell metamagic on, say, *Cure Wounds*, if I gained *Cure Wounds* from being a Bard. Am I correct in this?

Speaking as both a player and DM here. I wanna know what I can build around.

Comment: Related: [If I multiclass into Paladin, can I use up any class's spell slots for Divine Smite?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56889/if-i-multiclass-into-paladin-can-i-use-up-any-classs-spell-slots-for-divine-sm)