# Does multiclassing suddenly allow you to cast spells from Magic Initiate (or other similar features/feats) using more spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, multi-classing, spellcasting, spell-slots

The following question already exists and explains that you *can* cast spells gained from the Magic Initiate feat if **and only if** the class you choose is the same as one of your own:

- [Can you cast a spell learned from the Magic Initiate feat using spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68451)

So let's assume a Wizard take the Magic Initiate feat and learns the [*healing word*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-word) spell with the Bard option of the feat. It is established already that they cannot cast this spell using their own spell slots, for some more supporting evidence classes received [errata](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) and the Wizard class now states the following under "[Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#Spellcasting-410)" (the bolded word "Wizard" was added):

> [...] The Wizard table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your **wizard** spells of 1st level and higher. [...]

---

With that established, I'm a bit confused what happens when this Wizard decides to multiclass into Bard; the [multiclassing spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting) rules state:

> [...] You determine your available spell slots by adding together all your levels in the bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, and wizard classes, and half your levels (rounded down) in the paladin and ranger classes. Use this total to determine your spell slots by consulting the Multiclass Spellcaster table. [...]

There is not longer a way to distinguish between Wizard spell slots and Bard spell slots. To me this implies the following:

Before multiclassing the Wizard could not use *any* of their spell slots to cast *healing word*, but by gaining one level of Bard they can now use *all* of them. Is this truly the case or have I missed a rule somewhere?

Comment: Semi-related (the ranger's Primeval Awareness feature mentions expending a "ranger spell slot"): [How does the Ranger's Primeval Awareness feature work when multiclassed into another class with the Spellcasting feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158456/how-does-the-rangers-primeval-awareness-feature-work-when-multiclassed-into-ano), [Can a Warlock spell slot be used with the Ranger's Primeval Awareness feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158525/can-a-warlock-spell-slot-be-used-with-the-rangers-primeval-awareness-feature)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  You have read all the rules correctly.

Once the Wizard takes a level of Bard, the spell learned from Magic Initiate is from (one of) the character's own classes, and is therefore eligible to be cast from spell slots; multiclassed casters can use any of their multiclass spell slots for a spell from any of their classes; it all checks out.

Comment: It would be helpful to include more detail. Short answers like this isn't very helpful for this site.

Comment: @Eternallord66: the OP has already cited all of the relevant rules in all of their relevant text, I'm not certain what additional detail there is to add.

Comment: @Eternallord66 Yeah I was mostly just hoping/wondering if I'd somehow missed a rule somewhere since this scenario seemed particularly odd